# pip3 not installing packages

Tags: python, subprocess, installation

I enter the following line into terminal:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

this gives me:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 233, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 251, in main
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)) as session:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 72, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/download.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    from pip._vendor import distro
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1050, in <module>
    _distro = LinuxDistribution()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 594, in __init__
    if include_lsb else {}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 931, in _get_lsb_release_info
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout, stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Im thinking its a path issue but im not really sure.

Comment: What is the output of `lsb_release -a` ?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Try to reinstall `lsb-release` (ubuntu or debian package).

Comment: @AndréFreitas the output is the following 

 ` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ImportError: No module named 'lsb_release' `

Comment: @PrakashPalnati im using elementary os

Comment: were you deleting packages from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/022248f6484fe87dc0ef5aec3437f4c7971fd14b/pip/_vendor/distro.py#L916) with the `distro` package vendored by pip. The bug [has been solved](https://github.com/nir0s/distro/pull/197/files#diff-4329dcc8366b71b6919aa801100ede4fR917) but the latest version of pip uses and very old version of `distro` which doesn't have this bug fix applied.

For now, you can simply try to make the executable available in the path.